# Liferay 6.1 : Themes are not reflected in Website

Tags: liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6.1 with Tomcat , i have created Themes and deployed them but somehow they are not being reflected in Web Site . Please tell me if i am doing anything wrong .

These are the steps i followed

1. Created a Theme called as TestTheme-theme using Liferay Eclipse Plugin
2. Ran the build.xml file  The build was successful)
3. It created a _diffs directory (folder under the PLUGINSDK\themes\TestTheme-theme\docroot
4. Navigated to Liferays  tomcat-7.0.22\webapps\ROOT\html\themes_styled and copied the css folder to the newly created _diffs folder .
5. Modified the custom.css file under the _diffs folder .
6. Ran build.xml for Deployment ( The Build was successfull)
7. Opened browser http:localhost:8086

I couldn't anywhere my css chnanges on to the browser .

Please let me know if i am missing something .( I am uisng Lifery 6.1)

And please see the image also [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must change the Theme in Page Management.

```
Dockbar -> Manage -> Page -> Look and Feel
```